# How to load a page with RichEditBox, so it's displayed stretched to the entire page?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, tabview

I have an App that has TabView on MainPage.xaml of my app. I also have ContentPage.xaml (note that it's not an actual ContentPage, it's just a Blank Page that I created and named it as "ContentPage") that only has one element — RichEditBox. When I create a new tab I use this code:

```
        private TabViewItem CreateNewTab(int index)
    {
        TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();

        newItem.Header = $"Untitled-{index}.txt";
        newItem.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };

        // The content of the tab is often a frame that contains a page, though it could be any UIElement.
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        
        frame.Navigate(typeof(ContentPage));

        newItem.Content = frame;

        return newItem;
    }
```

So, as you can see, what I want to do is I want RichEditBox to appear every time I create a new Tab and I want to be able to open, keep and write different text on each tab. It works really well, but I have one problem: I can't stretch RichEditBox element to the full page vertically. It fulfills the page horizontally, but not vertically.
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jriB.png)

I've tried to change margin parameters, tried to change Vertical and Horizontal Alignment, yet nothing helps to get the result that I want. I've tried to Google some information on this topic, but didn't manage to find any solution. I've been told that MVVM pattern might be what I want to look into, so I tried to look up some stuff on this topic as well, but still didn't manage to fully understand it. I apologize in advance if this is something very simple and basic, but I really have no idea how to address this issue. Maybe I'm thinking all wrong and there's actually supposed to be some easier solution for this problem. I'm very new to XAML and UWP, so any good and simple explanation would be great.

ContentPage.xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.ContentPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:control="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource AcrylicBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush}">

<Grid>
    <RichEditBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource AcrylicBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush}">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image Source="Assets/Square44x44Logo.png" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Width="20" Height="20" Margin="10,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppName" x:Uid="AppName" Text="TestApp" 
           Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" 
           Margin="44,8,44,896"/>
    <muxc:MenuBar VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,33,-5,0">
        <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Item1" x:Name="File" x:Uid="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Settings" Icon="Setting" x:Name="FileSettings" x:Uid="FileSettings" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_ClickSettings">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control" Key="I"/>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" Icon="Cancel" x:Name="FileExit" x:Uid="FileExit" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_ClickExit">
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </muxc:MenuBarItem>
        <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Item2">
        </muxc:MenuBarItem>
        <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Item3">
        </muxc:MenuBarItem>
        <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Item4">
        </muxc:MenuBarItem>
    </muxc:MenuBar>
    
    <muxc:TabView AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested" Loaded="TabView_Loaded" Margin="0,70,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <muxc:TabView.KeyboardAccelerators>
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="T" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NewTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="W" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="CloseSelectedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number1" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number2" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number3" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number4" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number5" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number6" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number7" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number8" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
            <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Number9" Modifiers="Control" Invoked="NavigateToNumberedTabKeyboardAccelerator_Invoked" />
        </muxc:TabView.KeyboardAccelerators>
    </muxc:TabView>
    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please share the XAML code of your ContentPage?

Comment: I added ContentPage.xaml code. I tried using Frame and UserControl instead of Grid and tried to change margin parameters etc, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem

Make sure to set the Horizontal and Vertical Alignment of the TabView to Stretch.

```
<muxc:TabView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Edit:

Change the VerticalAlignment of the Grid in your MainPage.xaml from Top to Stretch and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Well, it kinda changed the situation, but now there's other problem. Now, when I expand the app to Full Screen mode, RichEditBox doesn't fulfill the space completely. When the app isn't expanded, it looks fine (there's actually a bit of space at the bottom but that's fine. I need this space to add status bar later), but when the app is expanded there's too much space. Is there a way to fix this? Screenshots: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhyISBUsh4Z_pR2yU0qFvsYB1BzZ
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhyISBUsh4Z_pRymXOFrVixkQtxo

Comment: So could you share your MainPage.xaml code?

Comment: There you go. Done.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try it out. :D

Comment: OMG! It works! I can't believe it was something THAT simple! I have no idea why I didn't try to do that myself. Thank you! You helped me so much! I know I probably make this kind of mistakes due to lack of experience, but maybe you could explain how did you think of that so easily? :D I mean, you are probably very experienced, but I just want to learn how NOT to make such terrible mistakes anymore.

Comment: All I did, was checking your xaml layout for predefined Heights of controls, because It was a bit strange to me how the RichEditBox did not size with the window. Then I checked all Horizontal and Vertical Alignments and found, the mistake. You can also accept the answer If it helped you to let others know that this question is answered.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer. Do you mind if I ask one more question though? I have the "Exit" MenuFlyoutItem in the menu of my app. The code for that button that I use is: CoreApplication.Exit()
It works and my app closes every time I press the MenyFlyoutItem, but for some weird reason right before my app closes it kind of flashes for a second and the app is colored with the accent color of my system. It happens really fast, but it is noticeable. It also sometimes happens when I expand my app. Here's what it looks like: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhyISBUsh4Z_pR8inFO327YZAvXt
Is this a bug?

Comment: I actually don't know why this happens. Maybe you ask a new question here.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.